# Java how to make an Antialiasing line with Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, graphics2d, antialiasing

I am attempting to make a drawing pad using Graphics2D where I draw a line from two Points, a startPoint and an endPoint, within the MouseMotionlistener method mouseDragged, but whenever I add this line, it appears to be really jagged and rough. I have used this to help with AntiAliasing but it seems to do nothing.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

but it does not help whatsoever for high strokevalues.
This is my code for drawing.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //sets up graphics2d object
        g2 = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //draws line using points and shapes
        endPoint = e.getPoint();
        Shape line = new Line2D.Double(beginPoint, endPoint);
        g2.draw(line);
        beginPoint = endPoint;
```

beginPoint is given a value within mousePressed

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of (really cool) rendering hints!  I would recommend you start playing around with all of them and see what combinations give you the desired results!

[image: Smooth as]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Remember, graphics is a shared context, when you make changes
            // to it, you should also undo them.  To this end, we use create/dispose
            // which takes a snapshot of the current state and restores it at the
            // end.
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());

            g2.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

## Warning

`g2 = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();` is a very, very bad idea and isn't how custom painting is suppose to work.

`getGraphics` is nothing more then a snapshot of what was last painted during the last paint pass and will be invalidated on the next paint pass.

I would highly recommend reading through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting in Swing works and how you're suppose to work with it.

Drawing with the mouse is not a uncommon question and has any number of answers.  I'd recommend having a looking around at some of the other question/answers to see how this might be done and adopt them to your needs