# Why java Antialiasing doesn't works?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, antialiasing

I'm trying to create a game, and trying to make my text smoother. I have following rendering method, with antialiasing code:

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics pen) {
        offscreen_canvas = this.createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) pen;

        // prevent flashing
        Graphics2D offscreen_pen = (Graphics2D) offscreen_canvas.getGraphics();

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // and I do something with graphics created
        game_obj.proc(offscreen_pen);
        g2d.drawImage(offscreen_canvas, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
```

But the quality of text is still very low, doesn't improve at all.

I try to use this:

`g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);`

But there's no difference, still doesn't works. [this is the rendered text with code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MhcQ.jpg) two: [second text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULsX3.jpg)

However, with the same code, when I trying to change antialiasing line to any of these following line (not both of them, any one of them):

`g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);`

or

`g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);`

Surprisingly, Text quality significantly improved, and I don't even need `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);` at all.
image: [Improved text quality and its my expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lityc.jpg) two: [another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AGAs.jpg)

But the side effect is, my game is also slow down significantly. My game object move 20 times slower than my original code.

Seems like nobody else have similar problem with me. I use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431454, but I have no idea why this will happens at all.

So, why my antialias code doesn't works? what does KEY_RENDERING and KEY_INTERPOLATION do and why did they works? And why these two will slow down my game?

additionally: code of entire class if needed: https://qtext.io/o9nq

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent`, not `paint`.  The first line of code should be `super.paintComponent(g);` Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: `KEY_ANTIALIASING` controls the anti-aliasing of `draw` calls. For text rendering, `KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING` is the relevant key. But the fact that `KEY_INTERPOLATION` improves your result, hints that you have an entirely different problem. You seem to have a hi resolution screen with scaling activated but create an off screen bitmap image using the (low) logical size. Then, this low resolution bitmap is scaled to the screen resolution in `drawImage`, with better algorithm when using `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR` but still worse than rendering with the actual screen resolution.

Comment: And it doesn’t help that you have two `Graphics2D` objects here. The graphics passed to `proc` is not affected by the changes made to `g2d`. That’s why only the bitmap image scaling parameter had an effect at all. The simplest solution is to do as Gilbert Le Blanc said, override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. Then, remove your manual double buffering and let Swing do the job. There’s no flashing when using Swing in the right way.

Comment: @Holger I tried to use paintComponent, but java gives me a error saying I don't have such method, but I do have paintComponents. However, this one (paintComponents) doesn't works as my screen turns white and nothing shown up

Comment: You tagged your question with “Swing” so we’re assuming that you subclass `JComponent` which [has said method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)). If you didn’t, you should change your code to do that.

Comment: @Holger um, program is based on JFrame, is it not okay to use JFrame, so I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: Using `JFrame` is fine, but don’t subclass it to alter its painting algorithm. Instead, create a subclass of `JComponent` with a custom `paintComponent` method and either, add that custom component to a `JFrame`’s content pane or set it as the frame’s entire content pane (in the latter case, it must be fully opaque). If in doubt, go with the first option, `frame.getContentPane().add(customComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem with JComponent. `RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING` still doesn't works at all, but `RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY` do works, and It's no longer slow down my game. I still don't know why `RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING`, but doesn't matter